# Docker container not starting when connect to postgresql external

Tags: postgresql, docker, redmine

I have docker container with redmine in it and I have postgresql-95 running on my host machine, and I want to connect my redmine container to my postgresql. I followed this step : https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-redmine, to connect my container with external postgresql.

assuming my host machine with ip 192.168.100.6, so I ran this command :

```
docker run --name redmine -it -d \
--publish=10083:80 \
--env='REDMINE_PORT=10083' \
--env='DB_ADAPTER=postgresql' \
--env='DB_HOST=192.168.100.6' \
--env='DB_NAME=redmine_production' \
--env='DB_USER=redmine' --env='DB_PASS=password' \
redmine-docker
```

The container running for 1 minute but suddenly it stopped even before it runs nginx and redmine in it. I Need help about this configuration. Thank you.

Comment: Your db and the docker container are in different networks. start your conatiner with --net=host, to have the container connect to the DB.

Comment: I'd start by looking at your logs for the container. `docker logs redmine`

Comment: @Shibashis but I can ping my host inside the container

Comment: edit your question and past the logs like BMitch described